# Moq - Verify the last call to a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
public interface IMouseTraits
{
    void ForceCursor(Cursor cursor);
    void SetCursor(Cursor cursor);
}
```

1) How do I verify that the last call to SetCursor was with `Cursors.Arrow` (multiple calls to SetCursor and ForceCursor with varying arguments allowed).

2) How do I verify that the last call of both `SetCursor` and `ForceCursor` was `SetCursor` (multiple calls to SetCursor and ForceCursor with varying arguments allowed).

```
[Test]
public void AfterOperationCursorIsArrow()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IMouseTraits>();

    varw = new WindowOperation(mock.Object);
    w.Execute();

    mock.Verify(traits => traits.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow));  // ?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Callbacks to capture calls:

```
[Test]
public void AfterOperationCursorIsArrow()
{
    string lastMethod = null;
    Cursor lastCursor = null;

    var mock = new Mock<IMouseTraits>();

    mock.Setup(m => m.ForceCursor(It.IsAny<Cursor>()))
        .Callback((Cursor c) => lastMethod = "ForceCursor");

    mock.Setup(m => m.SetCursor(It.IsAny<Cursor>()))
        .Callback((Cursor c) => { 
            lastMethod = "SetCursor";
            lastCursor = c; 
        });

    var w = new WindowOperation(mock.Object);
    w.Execute();

     Assert.That(lastMethod, Is.EqualTo("SetCursor"));
     Assert.That(lastCursor, Is.EqualTo(Cursors.Arrow));
}
```